# How to use zsh tab completion on Git without origin?

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, git, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I am using [zsh](https://www.zsh.org) with [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) on Ubuntu 18.04.2. Currently, [Git](https://git-scm.com) is installed at version 2.20.1.

Whenever I want to push a local branch to a remote (`origin`) I try to use the tab completion in the shell as follows:

```
git push origin fea<TAB>
```

The tab completion results in:

```
git push origin origin/feature
```

I cannot push to `origin/feature`, though. What I actually want is:

```
git push origin feature
```

The same applies to `git checkout`.

How can I configure the tab completion to correctly (?) complete the remote branch - or am I missing something?

Comment: oh-my-zsh's git plugin comes with an alias to do this: `ggp`.

Comment: @jordanm While `ggp` might help with `push` it does not help with `checkout`.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a clash between git's own completion and oh-my-zsh's one.

I found a working solution here:
https://www.raphael-brugier.com/blog/fix-git-completion-zsh-mac-homebrew/

Depending on your environment, you might therefore want to disable git completion in your .zshrc:

```
compdef -d git
```

Also, upgrading your Zsh version seems to help, as this kind of issue [is reported as fixed on Zsh 4.3.10 and later](https://superuser.com/a/68322).

Comment: If I disable the git completion then there is **no** completion for `origin` or branch names and the like. Maybe, something about [my completions configuration](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/dotfiles/blob/master/zshrc#L33-L39) is just wrong.